# Talend Issue with Hive Command

Tags: hadoop, hive, talend

I am having an issue with running a Hive command in Talend.  Its a basic load command to move an HDFS file into a Hive table:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/Order_data.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE database1.order_staging
```

When i run it from a Hive query tool or the command tool on the server it runs fine but when i put the command in a tHiveRow object in Talend it fails with the following error:

```
Query returned non-zero code: 10, cause: FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:17 Path is not legal ''/user/Order_Data.txt'': Move from: hdfs://hive-server.com:8020/user/Order_Data.txt to: hdfs://hive-server.com/user/hive/warehouse/Database1.db/order_staging is not valid. Please check that values for params "default.fs.name" and "hive.metastore.warehouse.dir" do not conflict.
```

I have tested the connectivity of the tHiveRow object and it works. Any ideas what could be causing this to happen?

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Answer (score 0):

It could be permission issue. You should not have files under /user directly. It is meant for user spaces. What ever OS user you are trying to use with Talend, you should have permissions to that user.